# Conditional Range Reference with NPV

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-statements, formula

I have a table of payments:

```
Acct  Date     Payment
1     1/1/20   200.00
1     2/1/20   200.00
2     1/1/20   300.00
2     1/1/20   300.00
```

Is it possible to get the `NPV` for specific accounts assuming all payments are in chronological order?  For instance:

```
=NPV(.05/12,Acct1[firstPayment]:Acct1[lastPayment])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
=NPV(0.05/12,IF(A2:A5=1,C2:C5))
```

OR

```
=NPV(0.05/12,(C2:C5)*(A2:A5=1))
```

These are array formula and depending your version you might need to confirm the formula with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

---

Or if you have the dynamic array fromula FILTER:

```
=NPV(0.05/12,FILTER(C2:C5,A2:A5=1))
```

[image]

Comment: I tried both. The second one was able to return a value but it is off from the actual amount. I tried with table references and cell references. Hmmm....

Comment: Did you use Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode?

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: Yes for Ctrl-Shift-Enter and Excel 2016.

Comment: I am not getting that problem as you can see, so I am not sure why you are.

Comment: I tested some test data and it worked. I forgot I have the parameters of the PIVOT table I'm comparing it to to 1/1/2021. Is there a way to also condition one more column? I tried ```=NPV(0.05/12,(C2:C5)*(A2:A5=1)*(D2:D5>=A1))``` where D:D and A1 are dates.

Comment: No, it's a regular table. I am just comparing the NPV results from the table with a PIVOT Table PV Sum column.

Comment: Just thought of something the non IF formula will not work as it will return `0` for false.  Use the IF and use `(A2:A5=1)*(D2:D5>=A1)` as the criteria.